# Model for multivariate ordered categorical data with a time-varying continuous covariate

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, time-varying-covariate

I would like to develop a model for multivariate ordered categorical data that also allows inclusion of a time-varying continuous covariate.

This is for different types of adverse events, that can each have grade 1-4 severity. For many patients I have repeated measures data over time. I would like to describe the probability of each of the adverse events, with drug exposure (declining over time) as predictor variable. Also I would like to take into account the correlation between probabilities (i.e. a persion with grade 2 nausea also has increased probability of grade 2 vomitting etc.).

Ultimately I want to be able to simulate time-courses for patients according to the observed probabilities of experiencing different types and severities of adverse events, taking into account the correlation between adverse event probabilities, and time-varying exposure.

What kind of modelling strategy would allow me to do this?